# My flights via Russia,if I stay on airport only,will I need a visa?

Tags: schengen, transit, international-travel, russia, switzerland

I have a **schengen** visa and I'm an Indian.I need to travel to Nice but the most appropriate flight for me is via Russia.If I stay on the airport only,will I need a visa?Also,will I need a visa if a flight is via Switzerland?What is the limits of hours I can stay on the airport of Switzerland and Russia if my flights via them?Please answer asap.thanks.

Comment: Switzerland is in the Schengen area.